# How do I get features from a geoJson load?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I've got some GeoJson loading into an openlayers 3 vector layer

```js
var countriesLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: '/data/countriesandstates.geojson',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
  }),
  style: function(feature, resolution) {
    countriesLayerTextStyle.getText().setText(resolution < 5000 ? feature.get('name') : '');
    return [countriesLayerStyle, countriesLayerTextStyle];
  }
});
```

I want to run over all the features in that source using

`countriesLayer.getSource().forEachFeature(...);`

However it never calls my callback, and if I try `getFeatures()` I get an empty array back. However it renders just fine so I know the data is loaded.  I even tried doing in 5 seconds later on a timeout to make sure it was loaded and parsed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
countriesLayer.getSource().on("change", function(ev) {
    if( countriesLayer.getSource().getState() === "ready" ) {
        console.log(countriesLayer.getSource().getFeatures().length)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Listen when your features are added (AJAX) to source:

```
countriesLayer.getSource().on('addfeature', function() {
  // process further
});

// or just once
countriesLayer.getSource().once('addfeature', function() {
  // process further
});
```

Comment: Thanks! My issue was also that I was building the layer twice (and hence not actually loading the one I was looking at I think).

Comment: Once that is called it seems that all the features are now there - is there a way to get a single "loaded" event?

Comment: @MrPurpleStreak you can use `once` instead of `on`.